# ffmpeg time format in filter_complex

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I wanted to trim video. I mean I wanted to select few sections from one video and then concat they or mix they together!

I did it.
But in "filter_complex" I can not type start point time format like:
hh:mm:ss.0
If I will type "trim=start=02:22:00.0" it fails....
Instead if I will type "trim=start=8520" then it will work!

```
    ffmpeg.exe -i video1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=duration=145[a]; [0:v]trim=start=8520:end=8553,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b]; [a][b]concat[c1]" -map [c1] output.mp4
```

So I should only type seconds!
Tell me why?
So help me to type time format in "filter_complex" like... start=02:22:00.0 end=02:22:33.0

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: This functionality was broken since July 2013. Fixed in June 2016.

---

Enclose it in single quotes and escape the colons,

```
trim=start='02\:22\:00':end='02\:22\:33'
```

Comment: this method did not work

Comment: What was the message or result?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/519309)

Comment: @Heptite what does not provide an answer - the comment or my post?

Comment: it showed me a 3 line messages...

Comment: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Comment: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x

Comment: video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Comment: this does not work, on windows at least. e.g `"afade=t=out:st='01:44:25':d=25"` gives error `Value 44.000000 for parameter 'type' out of range [0 - 1]`

Comment: @MikhailV the colons have to be [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132707/5726027).

Comment: @Mulvya thanks! now I see. So probably this answers the question too?

Comment: @MikhailV yes, answer updated.