# Trimming and joining media files using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, mp4, media

I am trying to remove a segment (00:26:00 - 00:32:30) from a video file `input.mp4`.
Since there is no way to do that directly using ffmpeg (as far as I know), I am instead cutting the segments which I want in the output and then concatenating them.

After searching a bit, I've found that there are 2 ways to do this:

- Using [`trim`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim) as mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/682534/241498)
- Using [`seek`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) as mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/863451/241498).

Unfortunately, both these methods are failing for me.

I am going to explain the steps I performed in both the methods:

**1. Using `trim`:**

**EDIT: This method works now; skip to the second method instead.**

Command used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=duration=00:26:00[a]; \
[0:v]trim=start=00:32:30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b]; \
[a][b]concat[c]" -map [c] out.mp4
```

Command output: [Link](http://pastebin.com/63rhB7P4)

The output file is less than 1 minutes long and is of just 6.8 MB, whereas the input file was 900 MB.

**2. Using `seek`**

Command used:

```
# Cut first wanted segment
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i input.mp4 -t 00:26:00 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 first.mp4

# Cut second wanted segment
ffmpeg -ss 00:32:30 -i input.mp4 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 second.mp4

# Combine all the wanted segments
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

where `input.txt` contains:

```
file first.mp4
file second.mp4
```

Command output: [Link](http://pastebin.com/wyrYhCtz) (The error is mentioned on line 90: `input.txt: Invalid argument`)

The output file I get in this case is only about 500 MB (input file being 900 MB), and contains first video + first few minutes of the second video.

My system details:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- ffmpeg version: [Link](http://pastebin.com/M4Sq0X9z)

**EDIT:**

Method 1 using `trim` is now working, thanks to @Mulvya's comment regarding writing seconds as the unit of time instead of the HH:MM:SS notation as it is [broken](https://superuser.com/a/1061283/241498).

New command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=duration=1500[av]; \
 [0:a]atrim=duration=1500[aa];\
 [0:v]trim=start=1980,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=1980,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];\
 [av][bv]concat[outv]; [aa][ba]concat=v=0:a=1[outa]" \
 -map [outv] -map [outa] out.mp4
```

**But, I still want to know what's wrong with the second method.**

Comment: In the `seek` method, why the duration indicator `-t` in the 2nd command?

Comment: @Mulvya It specifies the duration of the clipping. Now that you've mentioned it, I see that I've made a small mistake: instead of `-t 00:53:50` in the second command, it should have been `-t 00:21:20`.

Comment: @Mulvya Even after correcting that, I'm getting the same error. Alos, I've corrected this is the question.

Comment: `trim` does not work with HH:MM:SS [currently](http://superuser.com/q/1061274/114058). Specify in seconds.  And what I meant was since you want the file till the end except for a portion in the middle, there's no need to specify `t` in the second command. If you still get the error, copy the whole file to a new container and try again: `ffmpeg -i input -c copy new.mp4`

Comment: Okay, I got what you're trying to say. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Mulvya I tried the same thing after copying to a new container but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Some other potential useful information: The segment I'm trying to remove looks corrupted; the video seems stuck at the same frame as time increases.

Comment: @Mulvya Check the edits to the question. Do you have any idea regarding the second method?

Comment: Also, I have another question: Do any of these mehtods result in a reduction of the output video quality?

Answer (score 8):

The trim filter does not work with HH:MM:SS [currently](https://superuser.com/q/1061274/114058). Specify in seconds. This method re-encodes the video, so there is a reduction in quality. You can specify a CRF value e.g. `-crf 20` to control quality. Lower values produce better quality but larger files. 18 to 28 is a decent range to try.

As for the second method, try by specifying the cutpoints in the text file i.e.

```
file 'input.mp4'
duration 1560
file 'input.mp4'
inpoint 1980
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy -fflags +genpts -avoid_negative_ts make_zero output.mp4
```

The relevant options for the text file are [as follows](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Syntax-1):

- `duration`
- `inpoint`
- `outpoint`

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding quality. As for the second method, it still isn't working. The output file doesn't contain the second video at all. It's size is almost similar to the first video. [Here](http://pastebin.com/ZMCEDPwj) is the log.

Comment: Sorry, the concat list has to refer to the whole input file.

Comment: Okay, I tried that too, but I'm getting the same `input.txt: Invalid argument` error, with the second video file missing from the output file.